# Image created by UIGraphicsImageRenderer has different size

Tags: core-image, cgimage

I create a UIGraphicsImageRenderer with a size but the I get a cgImage with a different size ??

[image]

let string = NSAttributedString (
            string: "0",
            attributes: attributeDict)
        let size = string.size()
        print(size)
        let traitCollection = UITraitCollection(displayScale: 1.0)
        let rendererFormat = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat(for: traitCollection)

```
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size), format: rendererFormat)
    let im = renderer.image{ (context) in
        UIColor.black.setStroke()
        let element = CGFloat(grayShade)/CGFloat(255)
        let color = UIColor(red: element, green: element, blue: element, alpha: 1)
        print(color)
        color.setFill()
        context.stroke(renderer.format.bounds)
        context.fill(renderer.format.bounds)
        let rect = context.format.bounds
        print(rect)
        string.draw(in: rect)
    }

    let cg = im.cgImage
    return cg!
```

Comment: I down-voted because you need to include your code, not a screenshot. Please, it helps others with your issue - search engines both internal and external - can search posted code, not screenshots. Add it (and let me know) and I'll gladly change things to an upvote!

Answer (score 3):

The `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` has a scale associated with it that determines how the size (in points) that you create it with translates to actual pixels. By default, this scale is the same as that of the main display.

You can change the scale by initializing the renderer with a different format:

```
let traitCollection = UITraitCollection(displayScale: 1.0)
let rendererFormat = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat(for: traitCollection)
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size), format: rendererFormat)
```

Comment: Solved The Problem.